# Checkers and EqProp

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am going through the [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/) and the chapter on applicatives started using the [checkers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers) library for testing.

This library introduces the `EqProp` typeclass, and I don't understand how it differs from `Eq`. Most of the examples that call for `EqProp` use `Eq` under the hood anyway.

Why do people use checkers over QuickCheck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This library introduces the `EqProp` typeclass, and I don't understand how this differs from `Eq`.

`(==)` from `Eq` gives you a `Bool`; `(=-=)` from `EqProp` gives you a QuickCheck `Property`. If you have an instance of `Eq`, you can also make it an `EqProp` instance, [as witnessed by `eq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.4.9.5/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Checkers.html#v:eq). The interesting instances of `EqProp` are those that *aren't* instances of `Eq`, such as functions (cf. [Li-yao Xia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49663627/2751851)).

> Why do people use checkers over Quickcheck?

Checkers is a set of extra tools built upon QuickCheck. As its [readme](https://github.com/conal/checkers) and [Hackage description](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers) suggest, one of its goals is making it easy to express class laws as Quickcheck properties. For instance, note how the definition of [the `applicative` "test batch"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.4.9.5/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Classes.html#v:applicative), which I will quote below, looks a lot like how we often write the `Applicative` laws, and is nicely self-documenting.

(Feel free to skip the bookkeeping constraints in the top-level signature. Also note that the `m (a,b,c)` argument is, in a simplest-thing-that-could-possibly-work fashion, only used for type specialisation, the intent being that you pass e.g. `undefined :: [(Int,Int,Int)]` to test the list instance of `Applicative`.)

```
-- | Properties to check that the 'Applicative' @m@ satisfies the applicative
-- properties
applicative :: forall m a b c.
               ( Applicative m
               , Arbitrary a, CoArbitrary a, Arbitrary b, Arbitrary (m a)
               , Arbitrary (m (b -> c)), Show (m (b -> c))
               , Arbitrary (m (a -> b)), Show (m (a -> b))
               , Show a, Show (m a)
               , EqProp (m a), EqProp (m b), EqProp (m c)
               ) =>
               m (a,b,c) -> TestBatch
applicative = const ( "applicative"
                    , [ ("identity"    , property identityP)
                      , ("composition" , property compositionP)
                      , ("homomorphism", property homomorphismP)
                      , ("interchange" , property interchangeP)
                      , ("functor"     , property functorP)
                      ]
                    )
 where
   identityP     :: m a -> Property
   compositionP  :: m (b -> c) -> m (a -> b) -> m a -> Property
   homomorphismP :: (a -> b) -> a -> Property
   interchangeP  :: m (a -> b) -> a -> Property
   functorP      :: (a -> b) -> m a -> Property

   identityP v        = (pure id <*> v) =-= v
   compositionP u v w = (pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w) =-= (u <*> (v <*> w))
   homomorphismP f x  = (pure f <*> pure x) =-= (pure (f x) :: m b)
   interchangeP u y   = (u <*> pure y) =-= (pure ($ y) <*> u)
   functorP f x       = (fmap f x) =-= (pure f <*> x)
```

Comment: So it would seem that QuickCheck does not have the ability to do random sampling. Thanks for your answer, it is quite helpful!

Comment: @tesserakt QuickCheck can do random sampling -- in fact, that is one of the key ideas behind it. When you use Checkers, you *are* using QuickCheck and its random sampling; Checkers just adds an extra layer of convenience functions.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that functions and infinite values do not have *decidable* equality (`Eq`), but can be *tested* for it (`EqProp`) by observing a (random) finite fragment.

Comment: Right, so you sample a function and random input values and consider that good enough.  So then Eq is "decidable" and EqProp is "close enough"